# Use coefficients of thin plate regression splines in a clustering method

Tags: r, clustering, mgcv

There are numerous procedures for functional data clustering based on orthonormal basis functions. I have a series of models built with the GAMM models, using the `gamm()` from the mgcv package in R. For fitting a long-term trend, I use a thin plate regression spline. Next to that, I introduce a CAR1 model in the random component to correct for autocorrelation. For more info, see eg the paper of Simon Wood on [thin plate regression splines](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/attachment/2063352/0/tprs.pdf) or his [book on GAM models](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584884746).

Now I'm a bit puzzled in how I get the correct coefficients out of the models. And I'm even less confident that the coefficients I can extract, are the ones I should use to cluster different models.

A simple example, using:

```
#runnable code
require(mgcv)
require(nlme)
library(RLRsim)
library(RColorBrewer)

x1 <- 1:1000
x2 <- runif(1000,10,500)

fx1 <- -4*sin(x1/50)
fx2 <- -10*(x2)^(1/4)
y <- 60+ fx1 + fx2 + rnorm(1000,0,5)

test <- gamm(y~s(x1)+s(x2))
# end runnable code
```

Then I can construct the original basis using smoothCon :

```
#runnable code
um <- smoothCon(s(x1),data=data.frame(x1=x1),
         knots=NULL,absorb.cons=FALSE)
#end runnable code
```

Now,when I look at the basis functions I can extract using

```
# runnable code
X <- extract.lmeDesign(test$lme)$X
Z <- extract.lmeDesign(test$lme)$Z

op <- par(mfrow=c(2,5),mar=c(4,4,1,1))
plot(x1,X[,1],ylab="Basis function",xlab="X",type="l",lwd=2)
plot(x1,X[,2],ylab="Basis function",xlab="X",type="l",lwd=2)
plot(x1,Z[,8],ylab="Basis function",xlab="X",type="l",lwd=2)
plot(x1,Z[,7],ylab="Basis function",xlab="X",type="l",lwd=2)
plot(x1,Z[,6],ylab="Basis function",xlab="X",type="l",lwd=2)
plot(x1,Z[,5],ylab="Basis function",xlab="X",type="l",lwd=2)
plot(x1,Z[,4],ylab="Basis function",xlab="X",type="l",lwd=2)
plot(x1,Z[,3],ylab="Basis function",xlab="X",type="l",lwd=2)
plot(x1,Z[,2],ylab="Basis function",xlab="X",type="l",lwd=2)
plot(x1,Z[,1],ylab="Basis function",xlab="X",type="l",lwd=2)
par(op)
# end runnable code
```

they look already quite different. I can get the final coefficients used to build the smoother by

```
#runnable code
Fcoef <- test$lme$coef$fixed
Rcoef <- unlist(test$lme$coef$random)
#end runnable code
```

but I'm far from sure these are the coefficients I look for. I fear I can't just use those coefficients as data in a clustering procedure. I would really like to know which coefficients are used to transform the basis functions from the ones I get with `smoothCon()` to the ones I extract from the lme-part of the gamm-object. And if possible, where I can find them. I've read the related articles, but somehow I fail to figure it out myself. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you want the coefficients from the `$gam` component:

```
> coef(test$gam)
(Intercept)     s(x1).1     s(x1).2     s(x1).3     s(x1).4     s(x1).5 
 21.8323526   9.2169405  15.7504889  -3.4709907  16.9314057 -19.4909343 
    s(x1).6     s(x1).7     s(x1).8     s(x1).9     s(x2).1     s(x2).2 
  1.1124505  -3.3807996  21.7637766 -23.5791595   3.2303904  -3.0366406 
    s(x2).3     s(x2).4     s(x2).5     s(x2).6     s(x2).7     s(x2).8 
 -2.0725621  -0.6642467   0.7347857   1.7232242  -0.5078875  -7.7776700 
    s(x2).9 
-12.0056347
```

**Update 1:** To get at the basis functions we can use `predict(...., type = "lpmatrix")` to get $Xp$ the smoothing matrix:

```
Xp <- predict(test$gam, type = "lpmatrix")
```

The fitted spline (e.g. for `s(x1)`) can be recovered then using:

```
plot(Xp[,2:10] %*% coef(test$gam)[2:10], type = "l")
```

You can plot this ($Xp$) and see that it is similar to `um[[1]]$X`

```
layout(matrix(1:2, ncol = 2))
matplot(um[[1]]$X, type = "l")
matplot(Xp[,1:10], type = "l")
layout(1)
```

I pondered why these are not exactly the same. <strike>Is it because the original basis functions have been subject to the penalised regression during fitting???</strike>

**Update 2:** You can make them the same by including the identifiability constraints into your basis functions in `um`:

```
um2 <- smoothCon(s(x1), data=data.frame(x1=x1), knots=NULL, 
                 absorb.cons=TRUE)
layout(matrix(1:2, ncol = 2))
matplot(um2[[1]]$X, type = "l", main = "smoothCon()")
matplot(Xp[,2:10], type = "l", main = "Xp matrix") ##!##
layout(1)
```

Note I have not got the intercept in the line marked `##!##`.

You ought to be able to get $Xp$ directly from function `PredictMat()`, which is documented on same page as `smoothCon()`.

Comment: it's a start, but somehow I can't get the combined spline using these coefficients or a combination. Care to guide me on how I can go from the basis functions constructed with smoothCon to the final smoother, using only coefficient multiplications (basically doing it by hand)?

Comment: Thx for the update, but indeed, they're not the same. Actually, some basis functions are turned upside down even. Thin plate regression splines are indeed a penalized analysis, and the mixed in gamm isn't making things easier either. I'm afraid I'll have to get back to the math as well.

Comment: In relation to Joris' 2nd comment above, my Update 2, shows that the difference is due to `um` in Joris' code not including the identifiability constraints in the basis functions. If you include these constraints into the basis function, `smoothCon()` returns the same thing as `Xp`